# ICICI QRCode Integration CallBack url not hit in asp.net MVC webapi

Tags: callback

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public void SaveResponse(HttpWebResponse response)
{
    try
    {
         
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string str = reader.ReadLine();
        while (str != null)
        {
            _errorservice.LogException(str);
            str = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        str = reader.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Also note that your `catch` block is an anti-pattern.  To re-throw the original exception, just use `throw;`.  Currently this code is losing useful information about the exception when re-throwing it.  Though since *all it does* is re-throw and does nothing to meaningfully address the exception, there's no need for this `catch` block at all and it should just be removed entirely.